# Append to elements if condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a number of elements with a certain class and am trying to append something to them should a certain condition be true. Here is an example, but  it tells me this.value() is not a function. I am not sure how to refer to an individual element using jquery.

```
<span class="numbers">1</span><br>
<span class="numbers">2</span><br>
<span class="numbers">3</span><br>

$('.numbers').after(function() {
    if (this.value() > 1) return ('<span>Bigger than one.</span>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SkuW3/

Comment: It should be `$(this).value()`, but a `<span>` doesn't have a value IIRC.

Comment: Umm, there is no `.value()` it is `.val()`. Regardless it should be `.text()` in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.numbers').after(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 1) return ('<span>Bigger than one.</span>');
});
```

You had a few problems.

First, you need to refer to `$(this)` instead of `this` to use a jQuery function on it.

Second, use `.text()` to get the value of the element as text.

The parseInt(value, 10) is just a good idea when comparing text to a number in javascript.

Comment: +1 for faster typing *and* adding the radix into parseInt (as he goes and edits his own answer to add the radix in...) :)

Answer (score 1):

`this.value()` *isn't* a function - there's the `this.value` property or the [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function. But, in this case you've got a `<span>` tag which doesn't have a value, so you'd be better off using [`jQuery.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead. Using this you could change your code to:

```
$('.numbers').after(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 1) return ('<span>Bigger than one.</span>');
});
```